# How do I start a timer when I click on an entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, timing

I'm trying to start a timer when I click on an entry widget, but I have no clue how to do it.

I've got a program that loads up a tk window, and a timer starts as soon as the window opens. I have a button that resets the timer, but I would like to have it so that the timer starts only when I click inside the entry box.
I've also got a bind setup so that when I hit enter the text is passed into a function and printed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
counter = 0


def counterlabel(label):
    def count():
        global counter

        counter += 1
        label.config(text=str(counter))
        label.after(1000, count)

    count()


def game(*args):
    x = entry.get()
    print(x)


def reset(label):
    global counter
    counter = 0
    label.config(text=str(counter))


root = Tk()
root.title("hello")
quit = Button(root, command=lambda: root.destroy())
quit.pack()

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

button = Button(
    root, text="hit me to reset timer",
    command=lambda: reset(label))
button.pack()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.bind("<Return>", game)
entry.pack()

counterlabel(label)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind `Entry` widget with `<Button-1>` sequence with counter, So when a user clicks on the `Entry` widget the timer starts and the rest is as you've programmed.

**Try this:**

```
entry.bind( "<Button-1>",lambda e: counterlabel(label) )
```

---

Also I don't know why you made this function so complicated, when you could've just made one function instead of one inside one, in case if you have other plans to add more code in the functions later.

*Could be just this*

```
def count(evt=None):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    label.after(1000, count)

...

root=Tk()

...

entry.bind( "<Button-1>", count) )
```

---

**To stop the timer when you press the button**

For that you have to get an id of the `after()` function and pass it to `after_cancel(id)` function ( `id = after(1000, count)` ). It will start again when you click on the `Entry`.

**Here is the complete code**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

counter = 0
timer_id = None

def count(evt=None):
    global counter, timer_id
    entry.unbind('<Button-1>')  # So the timer won't go crazy on multiple presses.
    counter += 1
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    timer_id = label.after(1000,count)

def game(*args):
    x=entry.get()
    print(x)

def reset(label):
    global counter
    counter=0
    if timer_id: label.after_cancel(timer_id)
    entry.bind('<Button-1>', count)    # When reset the user can start again 
    label.config(text=str(counter))

root=Tk()
root.title("hello")
quit=Button(root,command=lambda: root.destroy())
quit.pack()

label=Label(root, text='0')
label.pack()

button=Button(root,text="hit me to reset timer",command=lambda: reset(label))
button.pack()

entry=Entry(root)
entry.bind("<Return>", game)
entry.bind('<Button-1>', count)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Please note that if the user click the entry several times, it will create several `after` tasks that update the `counter` simultaneously.